# how can convert hql to sql in hibernate 4

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate-4.x

I have method that convert hql to sql in hibernate 3 .but after upgrade to hibernate 4 i get exception for 5th parameter of the method .

```
    public String toSql(String hqlQueryText) {
        if (hqlQueryText != null && hqlQueryText.trim().length() > 0) {
            QueryTranslatorFactory translatorFactory = new ASTQueryTranslatorFactory();
            SessionFactoryImplementor factory = (SessionFactoryImplementor) sessionFactory;
            QueryTranslator translator = translatorFactory.createQueryTranslator(hqlQueryText, hqlQueryText, Collections.EMPTY_MAP, factory,**????**);
            translator.compile(Collections.EMPTY_MAP, false);
            return translator.getSQLString();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

how can i solve this problem ??

Comment: why this ? then you better to write sql only

Comment: because i want this code to get count(*) from hql that have group by.with your solution i will write twice code hql and sql for both time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 5th parameter may be null, as you may see on some [unit tests from hibernate source code](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/0a2a5c622e3eb30724e80bc8661c0ac55ebfb2be/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/test/locale/LocaleTest.java#L43).